# Avoid function to run again and again in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs

I created `component` which take `props` and this `component` `filter` the `props` but whenever `state` is changed it re-assign the variable.

**Example:**

```
const Foo = (props) => {
 const [state, setState] = useState();
 const schema = array_filter(props.data, "schema");

 // other Code
}
```

Everytime when `state` is changed `array_filter` method is called. `array_filter` function is custom function which filter the array. I want to avoid extra running of `array_filter` function. How can I do that can you please let me know.

I try `useRef` but not working.

Answer (score 1):

Just cache your result and it only re-calculates as your input is changed which is best in your case:

```js
const schema = React.useMemo(() => array_filter(props.data, "schema"), [props.data]);
```